# Collision force calculation with no future knowledge

Tags: forces, collision

For a personal project, I am attempting to write a fairly realistic collision simulator (for relatively large objects, not quantum stuff). As I was consulting my physics textbook and various online resources such as [this hyperphysics article](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/impcal.html), [or this one](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/flobi.html), it appears that all methods for determining collision force (or force/area) that I've found rely to some degree on conservation principles, which require some knowledge of post-collision parameters (such as distance traveled after impact, post-collision vectors, time of collision, etc.).

If I have absolutely *no* knowledge of *any* post-collision parameters, but I have theoretical access to any and all physical, material and motion properties of the colliding objects:

1. How can I determine (or at least estimate) the force exerted on each body as a result of the collision?
2. What properties of the objects do I need to know?

In case anyone has any additional insights/criticisms/suggestions about my methods, I plan to use the collision force to determine whether yield strengths of either material are exceeded, which can help me determine what kind of collision results (elastic/inelastic), whether penetration occurs, breaking, shattering, etc.

### EDIT:

What If I add the assumption that *all* colliding objects consist of a single material? i.e. no compound objects (such as cars) with multiple sub-components of various compositions.

Comment: You keep finding those methods because they are easier than working the full problem involving deformational forces (and in particular non-reversible deformations). The full version almost has to include some kind of finite element analysis (FEA) which is a major field of computation in and of itself.

Comment: You might also be interested in [scicomp.se].

Comment: I understand that a complete analysis would undoubtedly require intense computation... I was just hoping there was at least some kind of reasonable estimation technique that someone has used...

Comment: The only realistic way to proceed without knowledge of the actual dynamics in a real collision is by having a calibrated mechanical model for different types of vehicles. What that looks like for select examples of actually measured collision scenarios is shown in this paper: http://www.nhtsa.gov/DOT/NHTSA/NRD/Articles/ESV/PDF/18/Files/18ESV-000501.pdf.